# tkinter how to change attribute value of object using OOP?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I change an attribute on the object when the attribute is Frame? I want to change the color of the frame.

```
class MyFrame:
   def __init__(self, bg_color)
   self.window = tk.Frame(self.parent, bg=bg_color)

mainApp:
    frame_obj = MyFrame("blue")

    #want to change the color after the frame obj has been created
    frame_obj.window.bg = "red" #this does not work
```

Comment: You can change the options of any widget using the universal [`config()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter is based on different progamming language, named tcl and thats why things seem a bit unpythonic here.

The `tk.Frame` object isnt a pure python object, rather its an wrapped object in a tcl interpreter and thats why you cant address the attributes you intuitivly think you can. You need to adress the attributes in a way the tcl interpreter is abel to handle and therefor methods are created like `widget.configure`.

To achive what you want with your current code, it would look like:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class MyFrame():
    def __init__(self, bg_color):
        self.window = tk.Frame(width=500,height=500,bg=bg_color)

frame_obj = MyFrame('blue')
frame_obj.window.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
frame_obj.window.configure(bg='yellow')

root.mainloop()
```

In addition, the proper way for an OOP approach for a frame would look like this:

```
class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.configure(**kwargs)

frame_obj = MyFrame(root,width=500,height=500,bg='green')
frame_obj.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
```

This way your class becomes a child of the `tk.Frame` object and you can adress it directly. The syntax `self` in this context refers directly to the `tk.Frame` object. Also it is good practice to use the format of

`def __init__(self,master,**kwargs):`

while its the same for the parent/tk.Frame. It has a single positional argument, named master and keywords arguments for the configuration of the Frame.

Please take a look at a tutorial for [tkinter](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6lxxT7IdTxGoHfouzEK-dFcwr_QClME_) and for [OOP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej_02ICOIgs). If you had you would know that. Please dont feel offended, but StackOverflow requiers a brief reasearch and that includes to read documentation and take tutorials.

Comment: Just glad you showed me that excellent tutorials. Thanks for you explanation.

Comment: @AppCreator you are welcome. Happy coding!